# GUFW does not open for configuration in 16.04

Tags: firewall

Yes I have a dell Inspiron 15 3552 notebook, Intel Pentium N3700 with 4GB memory.

Every time I try to open the blue and white icon, the password window appears. this I enter with no problem but then the window disappears and I am left with nothing.  I keep uninstalling and reinstalling and the same thing. I finally installed it through a terminal window and the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install python-gi:  `sudo apt-get install python-gi`

In case it doesn't work (unlikely), install python-gobject: `sudo apt-get install python-gobject`.

On my system, `python-gi` was the missing package.  I haven't installed `python-gobject` at all.

Comment: thanks, I got it going with the second option.  still, when I go to www.grc.com for the shields up test, I fail the ping test as my machine can be pinged.  I fiddled around with it a bit and concluded I don't know how to ameliorate this so I am pure stealth on the web.  Please and thanks in advance if anyone knows how.

Comment: thanks, just accepted it.  Still, does anyone have insight as to how to completely render my  machine as stealth, as in it doesn't respond to pings?